# Parsing java code into Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I use eclipse (org.eclipse.jdt) for AST.

I think(?) I got some useful codes online to get declaration of fields and usage of them. But I got stuck on how to get the root node.

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(buffer.toString().toCharArray());
parser.setResolveBindings(true);

CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
ASTNode root = cu.getRoot();
System.out.println(root.toString());
```

If I do the following, then it prints out the entire java code I put in, not the root AST node.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the AST, but I was picturing this like binary search tree except that one node can have multiple children. ([picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree))

Any clarifications or help on this?

Comment: Why are you wanting to print the root node? What output were you expecting? Given that the Javadoc of `toString()` says “Returns a string representation of this node suitable for debugging purposes only.” this behaviour may surprise. On the other hand, I cannot readily think of a more natural behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toString` method just converts the AST back to Java.

If you want to see the full AST structure you need to use an `ASTVisitor` class and call the `accept` method:

```
root.accept(visitor);
```

where `visitor` is an instance of a class which extends `ASTVisitor`. `ASTVisitor` has many `preVisit`, `visit` and `postVisit` methods that you can override to see the different AST nodes.

Comment: I have managed to create an ASTVisitor with some methods in it (such as VariableDeclarationFragment, SimpleNode, etc). But my point was how to make them into a tree? Does AST has that functionaltiy or do I have to create my own method that creates a tree for it?

Comment: The AST is a tree. If you mean you want to print it out in a tree structure you will have to code that yourself using the various visitor calls.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That answer is actually what I've been looking for. I was fooled by the name AST, so I thought it had the function to make the java code into a parsed tree. I was hoping to convert java code into something like this: [LINK](http://www.oranlooney.com/static/misl/ast.png)